# map local address to external one?

Tags: routing, ip, ip-routing

Currently I have a network setup like this:

- Router (aka. OuterRouter) to connect to the Internet (localIP: `192.168.0.1/24`, externalIP: `<whatever, provided by ISP>`)
- Router (aka. InnerRouter) for local network. This router uses its external address to connect to the Internet via OuterRouter. It has its address assigned by OuterAddress to, let's say `192.168.0.100`. This router is a DHCP for local devices and manages network of `10.0.50.0/24`
- A device connected to LAN via InnerRouter that has a local IP of `10.0.50.250/24`.

I cannot access OuterRouter management portal from any local device since it is different network. How do I configure InnerRouter to allow any local device to access OuterRouter's management portal available on the address of `192.168.0.1:80`?

Ideally, what I would like to have is a local address `10.0.50.249:80` that is routed to OuterRouter's local network address `192.168.0.1:80`. How do I do that?

**EDIT**

- while been in OuterRouter's local network (by connecting my notebook with a cable to that router) I can access its admin panel by going to http://192.168.0.1
- while been in InnerRouter's local network (wifi or cable connected to InnerRouter) I cannot type in http://192.168.0.1 since it is not recognised (different network)

What I want is to be able to access admin panel via http address: 10.0.50.249 in InnerRouter's local network and get to 192.168.0.1 OuterRouter's local address (over http)

Comment: Your claim that "I cannot access OuterRouter management portal from any local device since it is different network" doesn't make sense. There is no reason why being on a different network would cause you to be unable to access the site. After all, every site on the Internet is on a different network, and you can access all of them. Something else must be happening.

Comment: It is available under OuterRouter's local IP address, so what should I type in? My device's IP is of 10.0.50.0/24 subnet whilst OuterRouter's locals are 192.168.0.0/24. @MichaelHampton Please, check more details in my question

Answer (score 2):

You need a static route on the outer router for the 10 network that points to the inner router interface , and a default route on the inner router that points to the outer one.